# How to fix my illustrator artboard problem?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

My Illustrator artboard in a new project is like this:

[image]

and i want it be like this(Without the white side out of artboard):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzEru.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for turn off artboard ruler follow this :-

Go to **View -> Rulers -> Hide Video Rulers**